# Convert IntRange to listOf String in Kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I want to convert a IntRange:

```
val years = 1900..2020
```

to a `listOf<String>` with all the values from 1900 to 2022, how do I do it?

I need it as a String list cause I'm passing it with other String lists into an composable.

Comment: "years.toList() is not working, it only puts the IntRange itself into a List" -- not [according to JetBrains](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/-int-range/) or my quick experiment just now. It returns a `List<Int>`. IR42's `map()` call gives you your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val listOfStings = years.map { it.toString() }`